# How do I prove that $\frac{(3^k-1)+6k}{2} $ is the same as $\frac{3^{k+1}-1}{2}$?

Tags: induction

Use mathematical induction to prove that the following statement is true for every positive integer $n$

$1+3+3^2+...+3^{n-1}=\frac{3^n-1}{2}$

Here are my steps:

1. Show that $S_1$ is true

$S_1: 1=\frac{3^{(1)}-1}{2}$

$S_1: 1=\frac{3 -1}{2}$

$S_1: 1=\frac{2}{2}$

$S_1: 1=1$

2. Show that if $S_k$ is assumed to be true, then $S_{k+1}$ is also true, for every positive integer k.

$S_k:1+3+3^2+...+3^{k-1}=\frac{3^k-1}{2}$

$S_{k+1}:1+3+3^2+...+3^{(k+1)-1}=\frac{3^{k+1}-1}{2}$

So I begin by adding $3^{(k+1)-1}$ to both sides of $S_k$, and then simplifying from that point on until the final result is the statement $S_{k+1}$.

$S_k:1+3+3^2+...+3^{k-1}+3^{(k+1)-1}=\frac{3^k-1}{2} + 3^{(k+1)-1}$

$S_k:1+3+3^2+...+3^{k-1}+3^{(k+1)-1}=\frac{3^k-1}{2} + 3^{k}$

$S_k:1+3+3^2+...+3^{k-1}+3^{(k+1)-1}=\frac{3^k-1}{2} + \frac{6^{k}}{2}$

$S_k:1+3+3^2+...+3^{k-1}+3^{(k+1)-1}=\frac{(3^k-1)+6^k}{2}$

But this is where I get stuck...

How do I prove that $\frac{(3^k-1)+6k}{2} $  is the same as $\frac{3^{k+1}-1}{2}$?

Comment: $3^k\neq \frac{6^k}{2}$.

Comment: $$\frac{6^k}{2} \neq \frac{2 \times 3^k}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Proposition: $$1+3+3^2+...+3^{n-1}=\frac{3^n-1}{2}$$

Assume true for $n$

Now we must prove true for $n+1$:

$$1+3+3^2+...+3^{n-1}+3^n = \frac{3^n-1}{2} + 3^n = \frac{3^n-1+2\cdot 3^n}{2}$$

$$= \frac{3\cdot 3^n-1}{2} = \frac{3^{n+1}-1}{2}$$ as required, hence true $\forall n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$

Comment: I don't quite get how you simplified the numerator in the last three steps. Shouldn't $(3^n)(3^n)$ be $3^{n+n}$ or $3^{2n}$ just as $(x^2)(x^2)$ is equal to $x^{2+2}$ or $x^4$?

Comment: I thought that $3^n \cdot 3$ was $3^{n+1}$.

Comment: @Axop51 I don't have a line which has $(3^n)(3^n)$, the last 3 steps involve adding $2$ lots of $3^n$ to $1$ lot of $3^n$ giving $3\cdot 3^n = 3^{n+1}$

Comment: I apologize for my lack of understanding, but what do you mean when you say $2$ lots of $3^n$?

Comment: @Axop51 As in $2\cdot 3^n$. May I ask you to quote the step from my answer which confuses you, then I can explain it better.

Comment: I just don't get how you went from $3^n -1+2 \cdot 3^n$ to  $3 \cdot 3^n -1$ in the numerators of the third-to-last and second-to-last steps

Comment: How did $2 \cdot 3^n$ turn to become just $3$?

Comment: So we have $1\cdot 3^n + 2\cdot 3^n -1 = (1+2)3^n-1 = 3\cdot 3^{n-1}-1 = 3^{n+1}-1$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56069/discussion-between-mrnovice-and-axop51).